# App does not work on a real device using application deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

This is my development environment:
OS Windows 8.1
Visual studio 2013 version 12.0 update 4
Nokia Lumia 630 on windows phone 8.1 (registered as developer)

After start the application deployment I get the message 
"App deployment complete" on Visual Studio and the app-launcher appears on my device but when I tap on it on Lumia I just can see "...loading"  and after 2 minutes a white screen.
The .xap is not mine.The app works perfecly running the application deployment in my college computer.
Any idea about what the app does not work using my visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
It was the device language :
My device language was set on English but the app was developed in French. 
In order to solved it I set my device in French and restart it. After that the app works perfectly.